# F# match with mutable

Tags: f#

Just started playing with F# and I want to create some mutable model inside my app to play with, using F# discriminated union instead of class hierarchy. However there seems no way to "downcast" a discriminated union and "match with" doesn't propagate mutability. What should I do?

```
type Foo = {
    mutable x: int
}

type FooBar = 
    | Foo of Foo
    | Bar

let f = {x = 2};
do f.x <- 3; //All ok

let fb = Foo {x = 1}
do match fb with
    | Foo {x = x} -> x <- 2 //"This value is not mutable"
    | Bar -> ()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your problem is, that you match/deconstruct `fb` into a new pattern/value `x : int` (that is not the same as the `f.x` at all!) which will of course be immutable (as bindings/values in F# are by default).

you probably see this much better if you don't give both (the value and the pattern) the same name:

```
> match fb with Foo { x = y } -> y;;
val it : int = 1
```

see you match `x` against `y` so `y` will get the value of `x` (but will not be mutable)

---

#### situation in `C#`

let's look at what would be a similar situation in C#

assuming you have a `Foo` class:

```
class Foo { public int x { get; set; } }
```

and a `FooBar` base-class with

```
class Foo2 : FooBar 
{ 
    public Foo Value { get; } 
}
```

(I striped the ctors because I am to lazy - you get the idea)

now you would do this:

```
var fb = new Foo2(new Foo(1));
var x = fb.Value.x;
x := 2;
```

do you think that `fb.Value.x` will be `2` or `1`? ;)

---

#### how to pattern-match / mutate

use

```
let fb = Foo {x = 1}
do match fb with
    | Foo f -> f.x <- 2
    | Bar -> ()
```

instead - this will deconstruct `f` out of `fb` and then you can set the mutable record-field `f.x`

But I would suggest not starting to learn F# by trying out how to use *mutable* values - try to learn using **immutability** as much as you can istead :)